# how to turn on camera flash light or torch light using qml?

Tags: qt, qml

So i am working on a mobile app and i need to apply the touch feature on my app,How Can I turn on camera flash light or torch light on Button click using qml ? Is there any way to do this? I am using pure qml no c++ not qt

Comment: You're using QML without Qt?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it with the [`CameraFlash.mode` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameraflash.html#mode-prop) :

```
Camera {
    // ...
    flash.mode: Camera.FlashOn // or Camera.FlashTorch
}
```

Note that this feature is not always supported, you can check the available modes with [`CameraFlash.supportedModes`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qml-qtmultimedia-cameraflash.html#supportedModes-prop).

Comment: Great find! Everyday I learn something new about qml ;)

Comment: The different multimedia properties of Camera are weirdly documented, they are mentioned in the page but not in the main property listing.